# The title of the "unanswered questions" page seems a bit misleading

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I would suggest to change the title of the [Unanswered Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) page from "Unanswered Questions" to "Unanswered Questions (questions with no answers or no upvotes yet)". Or perhaps add an asterisk and a footnote to explain what it means by "unanswered" in this case.

Comment: A footnote [like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jOf3Z.png)

Comment: basically, the page title is "unanswered questions" but most of the questions it lists *have* answers, which seems confusing...

Comment: That confusion then only lasts until you click on the link, because it's explained in bright orange letters afterwards. I don't think we should have the long title you propose. And if we hide it in a footnote anyway, the orange text on the actual page will suffice as well.

Comment: @Bart see comment to the current one answer.

Comment: Why not just answer all the questions with good answers or upvote all the answers? :P

Comment: I would also like to peruse questions that have received *no* service, whatsoever. Denying us this is their stop-gap to FGitW?

Answer (score 5):

We already have that, not as a footnote but as a very clear, very brightly colored subheader, as pointed by Tim Stone:

[image: Subheader]

A lengthy title is never good, and since the confusion is cleared rather immediately, I see no need to change anything at this point.

Comment: Unfortunately, at least for mep, this is located on the right so the subheader connection isn't quite clear...in fact it's almost like it's saying "this is a sub type of all unanswered questions" which leaves me wondering "so where are the real unanswered ones" suggestion/feature request: move it directly under the title.

Comment: I might also suggest a more accurate (but still small) title for that page, like "unconfirmed answers" or the like...to cause less confusion for users. thanks!